# To + Gerund in a particular case

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Regarding the sentence marked in yellow, also, there might be other errors, I am especially not sure about **to furnishing** and **to delivering**. Should they be as they are or should I write **to furnish** and **to deliver**?

> A. I. Root speculated that Orville might have done it because he was averse **to furnishing** machines for war. ... The telegram sent by Brigadier General James Allen to the Wrights, on February 8, 1908, informing them their bid, **to delivering** a flying machine to the US War Department for $25,000, had been accepted, is evidence the two inventors did not care too much their machines would be used for military purposes.

Comment: You're misparsing. It's not ***to furnishing***, it's ***averse to** [something]*, where ***furnishing*** is a "gerund" verb form used as a noun (in a context where one might use an "ordinary" noun such as ***He was averse to the military***).

Comment: ...the second one is a mistake. It should be *the telegram informing them their bid **to deliver** a flying machine had been accepted*.

Comment: This is the original written by Amos Root: "I have been wondering if it were not possible that Orville Wright has sold out because he is averse to furnishing machines for war, as his father has been all his life a minister; and from what I know of the man I can readily imagine that he would be strongly averse to the manufacture of any machine designed for the purpose of killing people." / "to delivering" was written by me because I was influenced by "to furnishing". It is still not clear to me why "to furnishing" is ok and "to delivering" is not in the given context.

Comment: RobertWerner: "I am allergic to peanuts but I like to eating strawberries."  Do you understand how "allergic to peanuts" is OK but "I like to eating" is wrong?  If so, you're halfway there: "peanuts" is a noun (so "to peanuts" is a prepositional phrase), but "eat" is a verb (but should be written "I like eating" or "I like to eat"). Now: in your example (as @FumbleFingers says), "furnishing" is a gerund, which functions as a noun.  "averse to furnishing" is grammatically the same as "allergic to peanuts".

Comment: My case is a bit different: "He is averse to furnishing machines but his bid, to deliver them, was accepted." (Your example can explain why "averse to furnishing" is a correct construction. However, regarding why "his bid, to deliver them" should use "deliver" and not "delivering", your explanation fails a bit because "I like to eat" or "I like eating" is a different case in which a verb follows another (like) while in my situation a verb (to deliver) follows a noun (bid) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

1) "Averse to."

2) "To deliver a flying machine."

**Long Answer**

"To" is acting as two different things in your two statements.

In Number 2, "to" is part of the verb that follows it.

> To deliver a flying machine = **To-infinitive**.

In Number 1, "to" is part of the adjective that precedes it.

> "Averse to furnishing machines = Averse to + furnishing machines = Adjective + **Preposition** + Noun."

That's why the two are treated differently.

Meanwhile, "averse to" is one of those phrases that always takes a gerund after it; that's why it's not "averse to furnish."

And if it helps, you could also say,

> "Delivering a flying machine."

In this way, you'll see that "to deliver" is actually acting as a noun, not as a verb, same as the first one, "furnishing machines."